# Android Camera2: the most optimal and fast way to change the output surface set on-the-fly

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec, android-camera2

I'm making a video streaming app that adapts the video bitrate to the available uplink bandwidth and I'd like it to change the video resolution dynamically so that there aren't as much compression artifacts on lower bitrates. While I've got this working by releasing the `MediaCodec` and calling `abortCaptures()` and `stopRepeating()` on the `CameraCaptureSession` and then configuring everything for the new resolution, this causes a very noticeable interruption in the stream - at least half a second in my tests.

I use OpenGL to scale the image for when the camera doesn't support the required resolution natively, similar to [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/lollipop-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/InputSurface.java). I initialize the capture session with two surfaces - one for preview to the user (using `TextureView`) and one for the encoder, that's either MediaCodec's input surface directly or my OpenGL texture surface.

This could potentially be solved by using `MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface()` in that I'll be able to reuse this instance of scaler across resolution changes and won't have to do anything with the capture session because no surface changes occur as far as the camera is concerned, but it's only available since API 23 and I need this implementation to support API 21 as well.

Then there's also the issue of surfaces getting invalidated and recreated. For example, when the user presses the back button, the activity, and the `TextureView` it contains, are destroyed, thus making the preview surface invalid. Then when the user navigates to that activity again, a new `TextureView` is created and I need to start showing the preview in it, without introducing any lag to the stream seen by the scaler/encoder.

So, my question in general: how do I change the set of the output surfaces in a `CameraCaptureSession`, or recreate a `CameraCaptureSession`, while introducing as little lag into the video stream as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the OpenGL context, which is what actually holds textures, including the one that the camera provides frames to, isn't associated with any particular output destination. So I was able make my video scaler change its output surface after it's been initialized, like this:

```
...
}else if(inputMessage.what==MSG_CHANGE_SURFACE){
    // Detach the current thread from the context, as a precaution
    EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
    checkEglError("eglMakeCurrent 1");

    // Destroy the old EGL surface and release its Android counterpart
    // the old surface belongs to the previous, now released, MediaCodec instance
    EGL14.eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
    checkEglError("eglDestroySurface");
    surface.release(); // surface is a field that holds the current MediaCodec encoder input surface

    surface=(Surface) inputMessage.obj;
    dstW=inputMessage.arg1; // these are used in glViewport and the fragment shader
    dstH=inputMessage.arg2;

    // Create a new EGL surface for the new MediaCodec instance
    int[] surfaceAttribs={
        EGL14.EGL_NONE
    };
    mEGLSurface=EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, configs[0], surface, surfaceAttribs, 0);
    checkEglError("eglCreateWindowSurface");

    // Make it current for the current thread
    EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, mEGLSurface, mEGLContext);
    checkEglError("eglMakeCurrent 2");

    // That's it, any subsequent draw calls will render to the new surface
}
```

With this approach, no re-initialization of `CameraCaptureSession` is necessary because there is no change in the set of surfaces that the camera outputs to.